# How do I prevent this form from being submitted if errors still exist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, validation, react-hooks

Below function always submit the form at the first render of the component even if `firstName` and `lastName` fields are empty.

```
const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});

const registerUser = () => {
    if (firstName === "") {
      setFormErrors((prev) => {
        return { ...prev, firstName: "Firstname is required!" };
      });
    }

    if (lastName === "") {
      setFormErrors((prev) => {
        return { ...prev, lastName: "Lastname is required!" };
      });
    }

    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0) {
      console.log("Form Submitted");
    } else {
      console.log("Failed");
    }
}
```

At first render, the value of `Object.keys(formErrors).length` is 0, but the errors are shown on the screen, weird!.

I tried to use `useRef` which worked, but it doesn't display the errors on screen because the component doesn't rerender with `useRef`.

How do I prevent this form from being submitted if errors still exist?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have called set state (`formErrors`) and then you try to read it immediately. So when you set it, it hasn't been updated yet, you are reading stale data.

To fix it use some local variable in that function (initially you may want to initialize it with state data) to keep track of errors, and then at the end when you are done with it, put that in state.

Something like this

```
const registerUser = () => {

    let errors = {
        ...formErrors
    }

    if (firstName === "") {
        errors.firstName = "Firstname is required!"        
    }

    if (lastName === "") {
        errors.lastName = "lastName is required!"    
    }

    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
        console.log("Form Submitted");
    } else {
        console.log("Failed");
    }

    setFormErrors(errors)
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, can you please refactor the code. I just did it and I am still seeing the same issue.

Comment: @MirStephen check it

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. We learned that we shouldn't try to read and set state variables in same function.

Comment: @MirStephen Sometimes you can for example if you call functional setState say two times, but you had a little bit different situation here. Inside `if` you were just reading it, not setting anymore